# Add a custom content block within an existing content block of Magento Core

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I'm trying to add a custom order attribute, that the user can define on the checkout page just after the list of the payment methods and before the button continue.

I want to do things as clean as possible, so I created my own module.

Im struggling with  something I thought it would be simple but I don't succeed to find a solution.

At the moment I only need to be able to display the template file in the following block .

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment
```

I created my template file which is only displaying a stupid text for the test
app/design/defaut/defaut/template/mymodule/custom.phtml
I know that there is no problem with this file while I used it on the index action of my module

I think the main issue is that I must not do properly the xml layout declaration.

Maybe you can help me

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<!-- this part is working well -->
        <mymodule_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </mymodule_index_index>
<!-- this part is not working at all -->
        <checkout_onepage_index>
            <reference="checkout.onepage.payment" >
                <block type="core/template" name="mymodule"  template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_index>
    </layout>
```

Of course my module is well declared as the index method of my module is working.
is it my reference tag which is not good ?

Thanks in advance, this layout organisation gives me headache,

Best,

Anselme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[David Tay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439441/david-tay) answered to me via  stackoverflow , thanks to him I fixed my issues, it was due to two mains reasons

- Developer inatention
- In the block where I wanted to add my block I was supposed to echo it

Link to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30067067/613123

Copy / Paste of the answer below:

As b.enoit.be noted, you forgot the name attribute. Besides that, you also need to echo out your block. This is your update:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment" >
        <block type="core/template" name="mymodule"  template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Your block is declared as a child of checkout.onepage.payment, which also has another child block (checkout.payment.methods) and this block is echoed out in the checkout.onepage.payment template (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml):

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What you need to do is echo out your block some where in the checkout.onepage.payment block's template, such as:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule') ?>
```